# Matlab: Plot colourful line over background gray image whilst retaining colorbar information

Tags: matlab, plot, png, colorbar

I am using MATLAB I would like to plot a colourful trajectory on top of a grayscale png image whilst retaining the colour information of the trajectory. For example with the data below, I would like to plot Data B over Image A. Without Data B turning gray and without making the colourbar represent the grayscaled image. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
%Image A
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
figure
imshow(I)

hold on

%Data B
x = 1:1000; 
y = x;
z = zeros(size(x));
lineColor = x; 
surface([x;x], [y;y], [z;z], [lineColor;lineColor],...
    'FaceColor', 'no',...
    'EdgeColor', 'interp',...
    'LineWidth', 8);
cc = colorbar();
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't seem to like to do more than one colourmap pet axes. By using `hold on` we're plotting both the image (gray colormap) and surface (e.g. jet colormap) to the same plot. By default from the non-RGB image in imshow the colormap is set to gray, and so it is the same for the surface plot. Trying to change the colourmap by invoking `colormap('jet')` changes the colormap for both the image and surface.

Seems that there have been others with the same problem:
https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/194554-how-can-i-use-and-display-two-different-colormaps-on-the-same-figure

The best solution appears to be defining two seperate axes to the same figure and linking them so that positional information matches. You need to specify which axis to plot to, so `imshow` has been replaced with `imagesc` which has more flexibility.Then you can define a different colourmap to each axis. Unfortunately, the colorbar probably won't play ball everytime so you gotta fiddle with its positional information a bit.

In practice for your code:

```
figure

%Image A
ax1 = axes;
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
imagesc(ax1,I)
colormap(ax1,'gray')


%Data B
ax2 = axes;
ax2.Visible = 'off'; % make transparent
x = 1:1000; 
y = x;
z = zeros(size(x));
lineColor = x; 
h = surface(ax2, [x;x], [y;y], [z;z], [lineColor;lineColor],...
    'FaceColor', 'no',...
    'EdgeColor', 'interp',...
    'LineWidth', 8);
colormap(ax2,'jet') % colourful colourmap
% Gotta reposition the colourbar, tedious bit!
% Position: [left bottom width height]
cb2 = colorbar(ax2,'Position',[.91 .11 .0375 .815]);
linkaxes([ax1,ax2]) % same positions in 1st and 2nd plot
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: You can probably also show an RGB image, so no color map is needed for it. Or you can specify colors for the overlay using explicit RGB values instead of a colormap index.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve! My Tuesday has been made much better haha